# Allow contributors to upload images but not delete them

Tags: wordpress

I enabled image uploads for contributors on my Wordpress site via the following code:

```
if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') )
    add_action('admin_init', 'allow_contributor_uploads');
function allow_contributor_uploads() {
    $contributor = get_role('contributor');
    $contributor->add_cap('upload_files');
}
```

It works great, but I also need to disallow them to delete the images they uploaded. Is there an easy way to do it? I know there's User Role Editor plugin, but I don't want to install it just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [delete_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_attachment/) hook or [pre_delete_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_delete_attachment/) filter for that:

```php
add_action('delete_attachment', 'wp66410923_prevent_delete_attachment', 11, 1);
function wp66410923_prevent_delete_attachment($postID)
{
  if (current_user_can('contributor')) {
    echo __('You can not delete attachments.');
    die;
  }
}

add_filter( 'pre_delete_attachment', 'wp66410923_filter_attachment_deletion', 10, 3 );
function wp66410923_filter_attachment_deletion( $delete, $post, $force_delete ){
  if (current_user_can('contributor')) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you!